# Unable to navigate within routes in Nextjs production mode by manually typing the url in address bar

Tags: web, url, next.js, navigation, app-router

In my Next.js web app, after hosting it live i am unable to navigate within the routes by manually typing the url in address bar. Example, my site is https://example.com. When i go to 'https://example.com/about' then also i am redirected to the home page '/'. But when i click the about button in my website then i am redirected to about. I also want the URL to function properly and help in navigation. I am using Nextjs App router and

```
output: "export"
```

in next.config.js.
Please  Help !!!!!

I want that when any user manually type '/about' or '/contact' then he should be redirected to the specific router without clicking any Link/ href button.